# How do I separate complicated measurement unit containing both characters, symbols and number from measurement value in Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am able to separate measurement units which are not complicated from measurement value if they appear together in DataFrame by using suggested answer provided in [How do I separate measurement value and unit into their respective columns if they appear together in DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75309851/16550496)

However, I couldn't separate complicated measurement unit like area from measurement value as shown in below DataFrame.

| measurments | value | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mea1 | 12.8875cm2 |  |
| mea2 | 33.1 mL/min/1.73m2 |  |
| mea3 | 2.53mg / dL |  |
| mea4 | 0.005ml/ min / m2 |  |
| mea5 | 0.8ml/m2 |  |
| mea6 | 0.73x10^3/UL |  |

May I know how could I separate complicated measurement unit from measurement value in Dataframe? The expected output is shown below:

| measurments | value | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mea1 | 12.8875 | cm2 |
| mea2 | 33.1 | mL/min/1.73m2 |
| mea3 | 2.53 | mg/dL |
| mea4 | 0.005 | ml/min/m2 |
| mea5 | 0.8 | ml/m2 |
| mea6 | 0.73 | x10^3/UL |

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['value', 'unit']] = df['value'].str.extract(r'(\d+.?\d*)\s*(.*)')
```

output:

```
  measurments    value           unit
0        mea1  12.8875            cm2
1        mea2     33.1  mL/min/1.73m2
2        mea3     2.53        mg / dL
3        mea4    0.005   ml/ min / m2
4        mea5      0.8          ml/m2
5        mea6     0.73       x10^3/UL
```